# Dynamically create a sum of functions

Tags: python-3.x, function, dynamic-programming, factory

I am having trouble approaching a necessary element in my program:

Given a set of points of the form ( x, y, a ) produce a gaussian function of the form:

[image: f(x,y)]

... from each point. Then produce a function that is the sum of all the sub functions created.

---

### Problem

Currently, what I would do is create a function from each point and append it to a list. I then create a new function that is the sum of the items of this list of functions. This works as expected but I want a more efficient method.

I don't use the sub-functions other than as an expression for the super-function. So I am wondering if it is possible to skip the first step and instead directly create the super-function from an arbitrarily sized set of points. Here are examples of the intended results:

---

### Examples

Given the set: [ point(2,1,4), point(3,2,1), point(1,4,3) ]
Produce: [image: Ex1]

Given the set: [ point(4,2,1), point(3,5,6) ]
Produce: [image: Ex2]

---

**Note**: Keep in mind that what I call sets are really just lists.

Comment: So you want a function that build the mathematical function to call it later, am I right?

Comment: @Tzomas Yes, that is the plan. Also, the mathematical function is not symbolic, rather it should be able to produce an output with integers or floats as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from math import exp, pow

class AllPoint:
    def __init__(self, array):#give the set of points
        self.points = array

    def applyGaussianFunction(self, x, y): #for each point sum the gaussian function result
        if(len(self.points) == 0): #if there is no point launch an error
            raise AssertionError("no points in the array")
        allSum = 0
        for p in self.points: #doing the sum of every gaussian function
            allSum += p.gaussianFunction(x, y);
        return allSum

class Point: #create an object named point (the keywork self means the object in question #this)
    def __init__(self, x, y, a): #this object posseed three attributes (x, y, a) 
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.a = a

    def gaussianFunction(self, x, y): #each point can apply the gaussian function on himself so each point can call her by doing ThePoint.gaussianFunction(x, y)
        return self.a * exp(-pow(x - self.x, 2)-pow(y - self.y, 2)) #the formula

p1 = Point(4, 2, 1)
p2 = Point(3, 5, 6)
points = AllPoint([p1, p2])
print(points.applyGaussianFunction(3, 4))
```

Comment: Looks good. Would be even better if accompanied with proper explanations.

Comment: Since I'm going to rest now, I give my upvote here. Hope I'll see improvements when I come back. Good luck.

Comment: @romph Thank you for the solution. A question: I have to use the sum of functions more than once so can it be done that I don't have to refer to the set of points every time?

Answer (score 1):

```
from math import exp, pow
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y a')

def sum_function(x, y, points):
  # use list comprehension to loop over the points and calculate the gaussian, 
  # then use the sum function to compute the sum of the list elements
  return sum([p.a * exp(-pow(x - p.x, 2) - pow(y - p.y, 2)) for p in points])

p1 = Point(4,2,1)
p2 = Point(3,5,6)
a_certain_set_of_points = (p1, p2)
```

to answer your question on how to avoid referring to a certain set of points twice, you could use a lambda:

```
a_certain_sum_function = lambda x,y : sum_function(x, y, a_certain_set_of_points)
print(a_certain_sum_function(1, 2))
```

PS: I would have given this answer as a comment on romph's post, but I don't seem to have enough rep points to do so :o